# crystal reports XI date range not selectable

Tags: crystal-reports

I have create a report in Crystal Reports XI. I have created a parameter field called DateRange and I have set it to allow range.

However, when I go to 'Select Expert', select the date field I want to filter and try to apply the parameter field, I cannot see the parameters field that I create. I can only see the dates that were in the database.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

thanks
Saj

Comment: didn't get your question... `How can you see the dates that are in database in select expert`? and you are not able to see the parameter when you are trying to create a condition in select expert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Select Expert, you need to choose "formula:" from the drop down menu and not "is between:". Then use the formula `{table.date} in {?DateRange}` replacing {table.date} with your desired database field.

Instead of using the Record Select Expert, I'd recommend editing the Record Selection Formula directly instead. The Expert is just a GUI front end for building the formula anyway and gives you more control over the logic.

Open the Record Selection Formula and add the following line to it:

`and {table.date} in {?DateRange}`

or, if the formula is previously blank then just add

`{table.date} in {?DateRange}`

Comment: Sweet as! I think thats what OP wants.